# how to change jssor full screen slider / possible?

Tags: jssor

is it possible to make this demo http://www.jssor.com/demos/tab-slider.slider to full screen height ? like supersizes carousel http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

Thanks

jssor

Answer (score 1):

In my case, adding

```
$("#slider1_container").css('width',window.innerWidth); 
$("#slides").css('width',window.innerWidth);
$("#slider1_container").css('height',window.innerHeight);
$("#slides").css('height',window.innerHeight);
```

before

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
```

did the trick. (gave the id 'slides' to the slides div)

```
<div id="slides" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 500px;
  height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
```